# Front-end/ReactJs environment based configuration

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, configuration, frontend

what would be a good way of specifying configuration for a front-end/reactjs client? The back-end is using Spring Boot and is aware of the environment it's running on.

I would like the front-end to have different settings based on the current environment (dev/uat/prod). Would you create a REST endpoint for this? Or what would be the best practice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) to do handle different configurations for different environments.

The idea is to define all those configurations in a `.env` file, then dotenv will create environment variables that you can access in your build pipeline, for example you could have configurations to set the API endpoint for that build, or a public key for a third party service.

This is how you would define your `.env` file:

```
API_URL=http://test.api.somedomain.com/v1
FACEBOOK_ID=12345
```

And this is how you would access those values when building your app.

```
const endpoint = process.env.API_URL;
const facebookId = process.env.FACEBOOK_ID;
```

Again, you will do this when building your app using webpack, gulp, grunt or any other building tool.

Comment: Thanks Crysfel, yeah I'm using webpack to build the app. So this should work regardless of what I'm using for the backend right?

Comment: Correct, this has nothing to do with the backend. I use webpack to build my app as well, for that case you need the webpack plugin, just import it in your webpack configuration file `import Dotenv from 'dotenv-webpack';` and add it to the plugins `plugins: [new Dotenv(), ...more plugins here...]`

Comment: Yeah, can confirm that it worked. Thank you!

Comment: But what if my build is triggered only once, but deployments happen for different environments. Now the Spring-boot is aware of the environments whereas, my React app was built and dumped into the target/classes/static. Now how can the react app have access to different env values during deployments.